# Removing user login button on Aviary Image Editor

Tags: android, aviary, adobecreativesdk

I've just integrated `AviarySDK` on a game that will allow editing a puzzle solution image. Everything's working fine, but I've realized that there's a login / register button on the `NavigationBar`.-

[image]

I'd rather not letting users to log in, as the game itself has its own login / register workflow and this might confuse them. **Is there any way to hide or disable this button on iOS and Android sdk?**

Answer (score 1):

The login lets users manage their Image Editor **content** (filters, stickers, frames, etc) across devices and apps with Creative SDK Image Editor integrations.

It's possible to remove the login button by removing all **content** tools from the Image Editor. When all **content** tools are removed, the user login will go away.

**iOS**
You can do this with the `setToolOrder:` method:

```
[AdobeImageEditorCustomization setToolOrder:@[kAFEnhance, kAFCrop, <etc etc>]];
```

[Details in the Image Editor guide for iOS](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/ios/#/articles/imageeditor/index.html).

**Android**
You can do this with the `withToolList(ToolLoaderFactory.Tools[])` method:

```
withToolList({ToolLoaderFactory.Tools.CROP, ToolLoaderFactory.Tools.ENHANCE, <etc etc>})
```

[Details in the Image Editor guide for Android](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/imageediting/index.html).

---

**Note:** Tools in the arrays are *inclusive*; those omitted from the array will not appear in the Image Editor. The order of the tools in the array is respected in the UI.

Comment: Thanks so much @AshRyan, actually I'm using tools methods to enable only a few of them. If I understand you right, the only way is passing an empty array of tools?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding you, just tried passing an empty array and no tools appear but the login button is still there. Am I missing something?